# On the definition of the length of a curve in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathcal{Z}, d)$ be a metric space and $\omega:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathcal{Z}$ a curve in $\mathcal{Z} .$ We define the length of $\omega$ by
$$
\operatorname{Len}(\omega):=\sup \left\{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d\left(\omega\left(t_{k}\right), \omega\left(t_{k+1}\right)\right): n \geq 1,0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{n}=1\right\}
$$

How is this supposed to be a good definition ? Suppose $\mathcal Z = \mathbb R$ equipped with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, and $\omega(t)=1$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Then the length of the curve is obviously $1$ but according to the above definition it should be $0$ because $d\left(\omega\left(t_{k}\right), \omega\left(t_{k+1}\right)\right) = |1-1|=0$ for any partition.

I feel a better definition should be

$$
\operatorname{Len}(\omega):=\sup \left\{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \tilde d\left((t_k,\omega\left(t_{k}\right)), (t_{k+1},\omega\left(t_{k+1}\right)\right)): n \geq 1,0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{n}=1\right\}
$$

where $\tilde d$ is a metric on $[0,1] \times \mathcal Z$. Then in my example, with $\tilde d(x,y)= ||x-y||_{\mathbb R^2}$, $\tilde d\left((t_k,\omega\left(t_{k}\right)), (t_{k+1},\omega\left(t_{k+1}\right)\right)) =|t_k -t_{k+1}|$, which implies that the length of $\omega$ is indeed $1$.

Could you explain why the first definition is the true definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion in your question. What we usually call the length of a curve is the length of its image. In your example $Im(\omega) = \{1\}$, which obviously has length $0$. The first definition does indeed compute the length of the image.

What you are asking is not the length of $Im(\omega)$, but the length of the graph of $\omega$. And the definition you gave is the right one, at least when the metric space is a Euclidean space. If $\omega$ is $C^1$, you obtain, using your definition, the classical result

$$Len(\omega) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+|\omega'(t)|} \, dt$$

You just need to use the mean value theorem and Heine–Cantor theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The "curve" which remains at a single point for the duration of a traversal has length $0$.

Since that is the accepted meaning of "length" I haven't read your alternative definition.